# Sirius Validator not returning all error messages

Tags: php, forms, validation

I'm trying to use [Sirius form validator](https://github.com/siriusphp/validation) to validate a login form. I'm having issues with `getMessages()` only returning one error at a time. The docs show this method should be returning all error messages.

If I navigate to the page containing the login form and fill in the form, leaving email and password blank, Sirius only returns one error message. The email error. As you can see from the code I am checking that both email and password are present by using `required`.

If I repeat the form submission, and leave only the password field blank Sirius returns the error that password is required.

Form

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="{{ name_key }}" value="{{ name_value }}">
<input type="hidden" name="{{ value_key }}" value="{{ value_value }}">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

Code used to validate form:

```
 /*
 * Validate user input
 */
$validator = new \Sirius\Validation\Validator;
$validator->add(
    array(
        'email:Email address' => 'required | email',
        'password:Password' => 'required'
    )
);

if (!$validator->validate($request->getParsedBody())) {
    print_r($validator->getMessages());
}
```

Output:

```
Array ( [email] => Array ( [0] => Sirius\Validation\ErrorMessage Object ( [template:protected] => {label} is required [variables:protected] => Array ( [label] => Email address [value] => ) ) ) )
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem,
but ended up using traditional approach, by using loops to extract message.

FYI

> The ErrorMessage class implements the __toString method so you can echo them out of the box.

```php
$errorMessages = $validator->getMessages();
print((string) $errorMessages['email'][0]);
```

or

```php
$errorMessages = $validator->getMessages();
echo $errorMessages['email'][0];
```

alternatively you can also use this

```php
echo $validator->getMessages('email')[0];
```